# Why do we use the masculine form in a Shabbat greeting?

Tags: shabbat, hebrew, social-convention

My Israeli friend explained to me that the word "שבת" is a feminine word, since the plural uses the feminine ending - it is שבתות.

If this is true, why is a common greeting שבת שלום ומבורך using the maculine format instead of שבת שלום ומבורכת ?

Comment: Your friend doesn't know much about Hebrew it seems. Plurals are probably the worst possible way of determining gender.

Comment: @DoubleAA Admittedly, there may be a piece of her explanation that I either misunderstood or omitted, here. I know that there are many masculine words with feminine plural endings, "layla" being one of them, that I can think of. If I discover more, I'll edit it in, B"N.

Comment: you basically already asked this http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/39067/759

Answer (score 8):

With respect to your friend, the fact that *shabbat* pluralises as *shabbatot* is itself insufficient for demonstrating that it's a feminine word. Lots of masculine words take that plural - such as אבות, for example - and some words can take both plurals (שמשים vs. שמשות, etc).

As it turns out, *shabbat* can function both as a feminine and as a masculine noun. An example of where a pronoun referring to Shabbat is masculine would be Isaiah 56:2 - שמר שבת מחללו (not מחללה). An example of where *shabbat* takes a feminine verb would be Leviticus 25:6 - והיתה שבת הארץ (rather than והיה).

According to [the BDB](http://www.ericlevy.com/revel/bdb/bdb/main.htm), the word was originally feminine but came to be thought of as masculine because of the influence of the phrase יום השבת, in which יום is masculine.

[**Note**: to see a discussion of this word's functioning both as a masculine and as a feminine noun, look at Tosafot on Ketubot 5a (s.v. שמא ישחוט בן עוף).]